# How to start from the next column\row in a 2d array on the next recursive call? (C)

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am trying to achieve something similar to this :

```
    int change(int coins[],int n,int sum)
{

    if (n==0)return 0;
    if (coins[0]==sum)return 1;
    if (coins[0]>sum)return 0;
    int options = change(coins+1,n-1,sum);//adding next value
    int self_options = change(coins,n,sum-coins[0]);//adding the first value
    return self_options+options;

}
```

I am referring to this line:

> int options = change(coins+1,n-1,sum);

Which makes the next iteration of the recursion start from the next element of the array.

I am trying to achieve a similar thing with a 2d array, but don't really know how.

Lets say I have a[N][N].
How can I start from the next row or the next column on my next iteration of the recursion ?

Thank you!

Comment: Please create an [mcve] of the program which executes the desired-to-be-recursive function once. I.e. provide a foundation which defines the 2D array in a suitable structure and shows how to do one of the steps which later should be recursive.

Comment: In the current shape (no MCVE) the question seems too broad to be answered.

Comment: I'll do it as soon as I can. Thank you for the fast reply!

Comment: @MichaBlum Hopping I understand your request I put an example in my answer where I go through a given row then a given column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way is similar with a 1D array, example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLUMNS 4

/* compute the sum of arr[row][0] .. arr[row][COLUMNS - 1] */
int sumRow(int (*arr)[COLUMNS], int row, int col)
{
  return (col == COLUMNS)
    ? 0
    : sumRow(arr, row, col + 1) + arr[row][col];
}

/* compute the sum of arr[0][col] .. arr[nRow][col] */
int sumCol(int (*arr)[COLUMNS], int row, int nRow, int col)
{
  return (row == nRow)
    ? 0
    : sumCol(arr, row + 1, nRow, col) + arr[row][col];
}

int main()
{
  int arr[ROWS][COLUMNS];

  for (int r = 0; r != ROWS; ++r) {
    for (int c = 0; c != COLUMNS; ++c) {
      arr[r][c] = 10*r + c;
      printf("%3d", arr[r][c]);
    }
  }

  printf("sum[2][*] = %d\n", sumRow(arr, 2, 0));
  printf("sum[*][1] = %d\n", sumCol(arr, 0, ROWS, 1));
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra rc.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
  0  1  2  3
 10 11 12 13
 20 21 22 23
sum[2][*] = 86
sum[*][1] = 33
```

20+21+22+23 = 86

1+11+21 = 33

Of course here the recursion can be easily removed, but this is not the subject and the recursion was requested

Comment: I see!
Thank you, I haven't thought about iterating through each of them separately.